# How do I print the current word being utterred in pyttsx3

Tags: text-to-speech, pyttsx3, gtts

The official documentation for pyttsx3 gives a variation of the following example for printing words that are currently being said. The only difference is that the print statements are in Python 3.x syntax instead of Python 2.x.

```
import pyttsx3
def onStart(name):
    print('starting', name)
def onWord(name, location, length):
    print('word', name, location, length)
def onEnd(name, completed):
    print('finishing', name, completed)
engine = pyttsx3.init()
engine.connect('started-utterance', onStart)
engine.connect('started-word', onWord)
engine.connect('finished-utterance', onEnd)
engine.say('The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.')
engine.runAndWait()
```

The following incorrect output is printed.

```
starting None
word None 1 0
finishing None True
```

How can I print the actual word being uttered?

EDIT: If this task is not possible in pyttsx3, I am also open to using any other text to speech library to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attribute `name` is intended to be a tag that is added to an utterance. You have to set it yourself as the second, optional argument to `say`, for example `say("hello world", "introduction")`. In this case the value of `name` in all of the callbacks will be `introduction`. From the [documentation](https://pyttsx3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/engine.html#module-pyttsx3.engine):

> say(text : unicode, name : string) → None
>
> Queues a command to speak an utterance. The speech is output according to the properties set before this command in the queue.
> Parameters:
>
> text – Text to speak.
> name – Name to associate with the utterance. Included in notifications about this utterance.

You can use this by duplicating the actual text in the `engine.say()` call, i.e., `engine.say(sentence, sentence)`. Then you can use the location and length arguments, which are string indexes, to extract the actual word from the sentence and print it in the callback.

MCVE:

```py
import pyttsx3
def onStart(name):
    print('starting', name)
def onWord(name, location, length):
    print('word', name[location:location+length], location, length)
def onEnd(name, completed):
    print('finishing', name, completed)
engine = pyttsx3.init()
engine.connect('started-utterance', onStart)
engine.connect('started-word', onWord)
engine.connect('finished-utterance', onEnd)
sentence = 'The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.'
engine.say(sentence, sentence)
engine.runAndWait()
```

Output:

```
starting The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
word The 0 3
word quick 4 5
word brown 10 5
word fox 16 3
word jumped 20 6
word over 27 4
word the 32 3
word lazy 36 4
word dog 41 3
finishing The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. True
```

Note that each engine implements the callbacks separately. The above was tested with the `espeak` engine on Linux, it might be that other engines for Windows and Mac implement it differently regarding the exposed information.

Comment: The onStart and onEnd functions print statements match your output. The onWord function was called once, but it did not print anything. I am running on Windows which uses the SAPI5 engine for pyttsx3.

Comment: @Ninja_Soup It turns out this is a known issue on Windows, see https://github.com/nateshmbhat/pyttsx3/issues/78. There also some workarounds are mentioned.

Comment: I tried those solutions as well, but to no avail. I guess I can make another ticket on their GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by replacing my pyttsx3 external library with an older version from [here](https://github.com/dr0id/pyttsx3/tree/447a473c8a3d9a0c906c9797e2e3459211a037cd). I also used the syntax that @Marijn specified.